# Using value from same row in Field Calculator of QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

I am using QGIS.

I have an attributetable with several columns.

I want to change the values of `column1` if they are `NULL` with the values of the same row in `column5`.

```
case WHEN column1 is NULL THEN 
END
```

How do I say "use the value from the same row"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The field calculator always calculates on a **row-by-row** basis. So you can use:

```
CASE WHEN "column_1" IS NULL THEN "column_5"
ELSE "column_1"
END
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `coalesce` to replace `NULL` values from `column_1` by `column_5`.

```
coalesce("column_1", "column_5")
```

Answer (score 2):

Open the attribute table and make it editable.

1. Select by expression `"column_1" isnull`
2. Along the top of the attribute table you an select in a drop down a column of 
   your choice. Select "column_1"
3. In the text box available write "column_5"
4. Click "Update Selected"

[image]